# Adding all possible sum, from a list of values to that same list of values in a list

Tags: c#

I have a List containing values 10, 20, 30, 50,30

i would like to add all possible sum of the values present in the list that is:

```
10+20 = 30
10+30 = 40
10+50 = 60
20+30 = 50

10+20+30+50+30
```

the list i declared is something like this:

List list = new List();

and values(i.e 10, 20, 30, 50, 30) were added using a for loop.

Done so far:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(3);
list.Add(7);
list.Add(8);
list.Add(1);

var length = list.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   var sum = 0;
   sum = sum + list[i];

   for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
   {
       sum = sum + list[j];
       list.Add(list[i] + list[j]);
   }
   list.Add(sum);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: What do you mean by: "all the values added to that same list should be unique values"? The list in your example does not contain unique values.

Comment: Ignore the unique part. what i have done so far is updated above

Comment: There is no code presented above. You should show what you have actually done so we can help...

Comment: Also, do you mean you want a list containing each of all possible sums, or you want the sum of all the sums (your title says, "Adding all possible sum", which is a little ambiguous). And what do you mean you want to add them to the same list? This is a very confusing question, so an exact example of what you are trying to do would be helpful (i.e. show what you start with and what you would end with).

Comment: a list containing each of all possible sums is what i'm looking for

Comment: @kri12345 - Do you mean a list of the sums of all possible selections of the source list?

Comment: the above code gives a list like this,

3
7
8
1
10
11
4
15
8
9
16
19

whereas the output should be

3
7
8
1
10
11
4
15
8
9
11
12
16
19
18

Comment: You want the sum of each set in the powerset of your list, excluding the empty set.

Comment: my answer is updated on how to create a power set, you might want to exclude the empty set for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<int>> getAllSelectionSums = null;
getAllSelectionSums = xs =>
{
    if (!xs.Any())
    {
        return new [] { 0 };
    }
    else
    {
        return
            from h in xs.Take(1).Concat(new [] { 0 })
            from t in getAllSelectionSums(xs.Skip(1))
            select h + t;
    }
};
```

So, given `var source = new [] { 3, 7, 8, 1 };` as the input I get the following result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with two for loops if you want only 2 elements. However, if you wanted to pick all combinations from 1 to all elements, you are looking for the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

I will answer it for just picking 2

```
List<int> sums = new List<int>();
for(int first = list.Length - 1; first >= 1; first--)
{
    for(int second = first - 1; second >= 0; second--)
    {
        sums.Add(list[first] + list[second]);
    }
}
```

You should also bracket this to make sure your list has at least 2 items in it...

**Edit:**
Since you've updated your question to show your implementation, I'll include code to generate power sets

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> PowerSet(IEnumerable<int> initialSet)
{
    foreach (IEnumerable<int> set in PowerSetRecursive(initialSet, initialSet.Count() - 1))
    {
        yield return set;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> PowerSetRecursive(IEnumerable<int> initialSet, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        yield return new int[] { };
        yield return new int[] { initialSet.ElementAt(index) };
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<int> set in PowerSetRecursive(initialSet, index - 1))
        {
            yield return new HashSet<int>(set);
            yield return new HashSet<int>(set) { initialSet.ElementAt(index) };
        }
    }
}
```

You would then loop like this

```
foreach (IEnumerable<int> set in PowerSet(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(set.Sum());
}
```

Comment: What about sums like `10 + 20 + 30` and `10 + 20 + 30 + 50`?

Comment: Thus see the linked article about Power Sets and how to derive them. That is a well documented subject and doesn't need to recreated here.

Comment: I did... I literally showed you the code to make a powerset, and the code to call the powerset and the code to Sum the powerset